# AWS Amplify CLI S3 Properties Contradicts AWS Control Tower Recommendation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-control-tower

AWS Amplify creates a `DeploymentBucket` with the following characteristics:

- The bucket is public.
- There's no versioning enabled.
- No logging policy is applied.

REF: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/blob/8c7a339df1c63bfdbccab3e97115bb69f20cc9c7/samcli/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.py#L66-L82

The account however was established under Control Tower with a standard S3 policies. Those policies restricts creating public buckets, buckets without version control, encryption, or logging policies (which definitely is there for a good reason). This differences between AWS's recommended deployment practices with AWS Amplify vs the Control Tower's enforced policies has put us in a bind.

REF: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/s3-rules.html

how could I navigate through this situation?